# Storage balancing in elasticsearch cluster

Tags: centos7, elasticsearch

I've a Elasticsearch cluster with 5 nodes. I've this used storage repartition:

- Node1: 76%
- Node2: 94%
- Node3: 88%
- Node4: 73%
- Node5: 74%

How to do to storage balancing/leveling the used storage ?

For the node 2 and 3, we arrived to the watermark threshold and the cluster stuck.

In my others cluster, the used storage is balancing/leveling. Example on an other cluster:

- Node1: 61%
- Node2: 63%
- Node3: 60%
- Node4: 63%
- Node5: 62%

Thanks

Comment: Do all partitons on the nodes actually have the same size?

Comment: @digijay Yes of course